./configure for emacs not finding programs on MSYS2
I am trying to build emacs with native compilation from source in MYSY2 on Windows 11, on my first try I got some warnings when running ./configure, nevertheless I tried to continue, then invoking make and make install, as far as I could see I got no errors, but the process did not generate any executable anywhere.
Then I tried again after cleaning the previous attempt with make distclean, but now it seems like the necessary programs are not cited in $PATH anymore, as trying to run ./configure now gives me an error of not finding any compiler. To try to solve this I simply typed packman -S gcc and after that the ./configure found gcc, but then it gave an error about not finding a library of imagemagick ( I was building with --with-imagemagick) but running pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-imagemagick I got that I already had imagemagick installed, pacman reinstalled imagemagick but the same error persisted, then I decided to remove --with-imagemagick.
Now it gives a error saying that to build with native compilation I need zlib, but by checking with pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib it also said that I already had zlib, it kept giving the error, then I decided to run packman -S zlib which worked in installing or re-installing the package (I am not sure), but I keep getting the error about missing the zlib library.
Hence it seems that the installed libraries and programs appear to have been taken out of $PATH. Actually, looking again at the results I got, it seems that I should be using the mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc package instead of simply gcc I have mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc installed since before using ./configure the first time, when I was setting up the necessary tools to build emacs (as I did mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib and mingw-w64-x86_64-imagemagick). And, in fact when running ./configure it checks for mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc but doesn't find, finding only the gcc that I installed after running make distclean.
How can I make ./configure find the programs and libraries that it needs to make the MAKEFILEs?

You need to read What are MSYS2 environments? How do I pick one?. Manually modifying PATH to include /mingw64 is wrong, it's a sign that you're not running the correct environment. Installing gcc instead of mingw-...-gcc is usually wrong too, unless you know what you're doing.

Please don't post the same question on emacs.SE and StackOverflow. Choose one to keep and delete the other. Thx.

@HolyBlackCat thanks I didn't know that, so I ended up using the MINGW64 version of the libraries and utility programs, which means that I should remove /mingw64 from my PATH and it all should work as if I had used Mingw64 environment in the first place, correct? The resulting executable seems to work perfectly (when I added the path to the .dll that it needs on the PATH) well, actually I don't seem to find the correct .emacs.d folder, emacs reports it as being ~/.emacs.d, which should mean the folder under .../AppData/Roaming/ but I modify it and it doesn't work, do you think I should redo?

"I should remove /mingw64 from my PATH" Assuming you build in MSYS2 terminal, you should just start the correct version of the terminal that adds /mingw64/bin to PATH automatically. MSYS2 terminal doesn't respect system-wide PATH by default, if that's what you modified. "you think I should redo?" I would redo everything just in case, and document the process this time, so somebody else can also try reproducing.

"actually I don't seem to find the correct .emacs.d folder, emacs reports it as being ~/.emacs.d, which should mean the folder under .../AppData/Roaming/ but I modify it and it doesn't work"
It will depend which tool you ask. If you open some of msys2 terminals, tilde in the path will be your /home/user directory. That might not be what Emacs started from some other tools, say Explorer might see. Make yourself a favor, and define HOME environment variable in Windows environment, and point it to your /home/user and keep .emacs.d there.

For some reason MSYS2 doesn't try to add the folder in which the Linux adapted programs end up in PATH.
So doing a simple export PATH=/mingw64/bin:$PATH solved my problem. Also I uninstalled the non-mingw gcc. Not sure if the mingw gcc and the program that installs as gcc are different, they probably are, but what sense does it make to make available a incompatible version of gcc?

You should really read the manual. You should not mixe msys2, mingw and ucrt runtimes. That is unfortunately one of the biggest nuisances with MSYS2. Msys2 is used just to build mingw and ucrt. Applications and libraries found in mingw/ucrt are native windows binaries. Msys2 runtime is posix, and resolves paths differently than Windows runtime. That will result in Emacs having troubles finding some programs and paths if you mix those two, for example gnupg home when you use package.el.
